# Example of reading well-formed and valid xml reading using xmlReader

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dtd, xmlreader

I m looking for some good example of reading a well-formed and valid xml file (having external dtd attached to it) using `XmlReader` of c#

Have googled it and gone through books but cannot find a good and well explained example.

this is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Catalog SYSTEM "marketplace_feed_v2.dtd">
<Catalog>
<Category>
<Name>Arts &amp; Entertainment</Name>
<Site>
<Id>ABC CORP</Id>
<PopularityRank>1</PopularityRank>
<Title><![CDATA[Some Description]]></Title>
<Description><![CDATA[Don't Have A Website? Create A Money Making Website]]></Description>
<HasRecurringProducts>true</HasRecurringProducts>
<Gravity>432.74</Gravity>
<PercentPerSale>75.0</PercentPerSale>
<PercentPerRebill>45.0</PercentPerRebill>
<AverageEarningsPerSale>28.14599</AverageEarningsPerSale>
<InitialEarningsPerSale>25.3445</InitialEarningsPerSale>
<TotalRebillAmt>28.55413</TotalRebillAmt>
<Referred>95.0</Referred>
<Commission>75</Commission>
<ActivateDate>2009-06-29</ActivateDate>
</Site>
</Categoty>
<Category><Site>....</Site></Category></Catalog>
```

This is the DTD File:

```
<!ELEMENT Catalog ( Category* ) >
<!ELEMENT Category ( Name, Site*, Category* ) >
<!ELEMENT Commission ( #PCDATA ) >
<!ELEMENT Description ( #PCDATA ) >
<!ELEMENT InitialEarningsPerSale ( #PCDATA ) >
<!ELEMENT AverageEarningsPerSale ( #PCDATA ) >
<!ELEMENT TotalRebillAmt ( #PCDATA ) >
<!ELEMENT HasRecurringProducts ( #PCDATA ) >
<!ELEMENT Gravity ( #PCDATA ) >
<!ELEMENT Id ( #PCDATA ) >
<!ELEMENT Name ( #PCDATA ) >
<!ELEMENT PercentPerSale ( #PCDATA ) >
<!ELEMENT PercentPerRebill ( #PCDATA ) >
<!ELEMENT PopularityRank ( #PCDATA ) >
<!ELEMENT ActivateDate ( #PCDATA ) >
<!ELEMENT Site ( Commission? | Site+ | InitialEarningsPerSale? | AverageEarningsPerSale? | TotalRebillAmt? | Gravity? | Id+ | PercentPerSale? | PercentPerRebill? | PopularityRank+ | Title+ | HasRecurringProducts | ActivateDate? )* >
<!ELEMENT Title ( #PCDATA ) >
```

can anybody help me with an example??

Comment: There is a nice tutorial: http://support.softartisans.com/kbview_674.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that `XmlReader` is read-only and forward-only.
so used this

```
StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(filePath);
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings);
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            reader.MoveToContent();
            // Parse the file and display each of the nodes.
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                reader.MoveToElement();
                if (reader.Name.Equals("Category") && reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                {
                    Response.Write("<b>" + reader.Name + "</b>" + "<br/>");
                }
                else if (reader.Name.Equals("Name") && reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                {
                    Response.Write("<span style='color:#1884A5'>" + reader.Name + "</span>" + " : ");
                    Response.Write(reader.ReadElementString() + "<br/>");
                }
         }
```

If any one with better example... i would appreciate..

Answer (score 0):

I would try to give [XLINQ](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=XLINQ+Overview&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F5%2F8%2F6%2F5868081c-68aa-40de-9a45-a3803d8134b8%2Fxlinq_overview.doc&ctbs=clue%3A1&ei=tFA_T_u0Eo-62gXproCaCA&usg=AFQjCNEU6RGH8EPax-yMXeidN6XxGp-B2A&cad=rja), read: LINQ to XML examples and try it out.

It should be very easy, straight forward, and is easily editable.

Comment: LINQ to XML is good but i have researched and found that XMLReader is faster than LINQ to XML as i have to read big XMLs from 20MB to 40-50 MBs thats why prefering XmlReader. Hope i m not wrong in this context...

Comment: a very good documentation on LINQ to XML. Wasn't helpful for this but have kept it as i know will be very helpful in LINQ to XML problems.
Thanks.